# Angular 2 + typescript Can't find property on compile time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to build a custom form validation method in angular 2.
The problem is that when I run the project I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

But if I ignore it and continue using my app I see that the validate function works as planed.

Anyone else face this issue ? Why I'm getting this errors?
I'm gassing that is somehow related to typescript rather then to the angular itself (I'm using typescript 2.0.3).

This is my code:

imports:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {RegexService} from "./regex.service";
import {FormControl, ValidatorFn} from "@angular/forms";
```

The custom validate function:

```
requireGroupMinAmount(minPossibleAmount): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl): string[]=> {
        let requireCounter = 0;
        if (!control)
            return null;


        controlsLoop:for (let formOptionKey in control.controls) {
            for (let formOptionValue in control.controls[formOptionKey].controls) {
                if (control.controls[formOptionKey].controls[formOptionValue].value)
                    requireCounter++;
                if (requireCounter >= minPossibleAmount)
                    break controlsLoop;
            }
        }

        return requireCounter >= minPossibleAmount
                               ? null 
                               : ["Please fill at least " + minPossibleAmount + " fields"];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child collection/dictionary `controls` is defined on derived classes `FormGroup` and `FormArray`. So, if we want to iterate `FormGroup` *(which `controls` are of type dictionary)*, we would need to do this check:

```
if (control instanceof FormGroup)
{
    controlsLoop:for (let formOptionKey in control.controls) {
    ...
    }
}
```

no compiler *(and even runtime)* will properly iterate only if that abstract control is `FormGroup` instance

Also, we have to be sure, that coming value is **`AbstractControl`**

```
requireGroupMinAmount(minPossibleAmount): ValidatorFn {
    //return (control: FormControl): string[]=> {
    return (control: AbstractControl): string[]=> {
```

and not the subtype *FormControl*. Only abstract base could be properly check if is it of some of its subtypes (e.g. FormArray)

There is adjusted code snippet ([check in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20AbstractControl%20%7B%20value%3A%20any%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20FormArray%20extends%20AbstractControl%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20controls%3A%20AbstractControl%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20FormGroup%20extends%20AbstractControl%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20controls%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20AbstractControl%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20requireGroupMinAmount(minPossibleAmount)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(control%3A%20AbstractControl)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20requireCounter%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!control)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(control%20instanceof%20FormGroup)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20controlsLoop%3A%20for%20(let%20formOptionKey%20in%20control.controls)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20childControl%3A%20AbstractControl%20%3D%20control.controls%5BformOptionKey%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(childControl%20instanceof%20FormGroup)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20formOptionValue%20in%20childControl.controls)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(childControl.controls%5BformOptionValue%5D.value)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20requireCounter%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(requireCounter%20%3E%3D%20minPossibleAmount)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%20controlsLoop%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20requireCounter%20%3E%3D%20minPossibleAmount%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%5B%22Please%20fill%20at%20least%20%22%20%2B%20minPossibleAmount%20%2B%20%22%20fields%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)):

```
requireGroupMinAmount(minPossibleAmount): validatorFn{
    return (control: AbstractControl): string[] => {
        let requireCounter = 0;
        if (!control)
            return null;

        if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
            controlsLoop: for (let formOptionKey in control.controls) {

                var childControl: AbstractControl = control.controls[formOptionKey];

                if (childControl instanceof FormGroup) {
                    for (let formOptionValue in childControl.controls) {
                        if (childControl.controls[formOptionValue].value)
                            requireCounter++;
                        if (requireCounter >= minPossibleAmount)
                            break controlsLoop;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return requireCounter >= minPossibleAmount
            ? null
            : ["Please fill at least " + minPossibleAmount + " fields"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.. the control  not supposed to be of type 'FormControl'? This is the type I defined it to be.. Anyway , I've tried to add your if statement with both 'FormArray' and 'FormGroup' but i'm still getting this error on compile..

Comment: FormControl will never be FormArray. Only.. if you work with AbstractControl.. you can check if that is of **sub** type  FormArray. So, do not work with FormControl... if that control is in fact having some children. If there are som child controls.. it is either FormArray or FormGroup. The check in answer shows, how you can check Abstract control... *(which should be the value coming to the Validator)* is of the expected sub type

Comment: O.k.. that's clearer now.. But still even if I change the type from formControl to formGroup and adding the if statement I'm getting the same error. almost if the compiler ignore the if..

Comment: from FormControl to AbstractControl.. that is the parent of those three.. not to FormGroup...

Comment: Still not working.. Even if I add something like control.hasOwnProperty('controls') it still gives me an error..

Comment: OK, I did adjusted your code to be working. Please, check my updated answer. I used FormGroup (not FormArray) and applied that again for child controls. Now it should work.. I am sure ;)

Comment: Now it works! Thanks a lot @Radim !  The error is no longer shown and the validation function works as it should be. Just a little note, you wrote 'validatorFn' and is should be capitalize (ValidatorFn).  Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great to see that sir! Good luck with angular ;)